# Display Component on click over another Component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `Menu` component. I'm adding items to `Cart` component by clicking on `Add to Cart` button.

I  also have a Cart icon which holds array of items in Cart.

```
const Menu = () => {

  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const addToCart = (el) => setCart( [...cart, el]);

  console.log(cart);

  return (
    <>
      <Tabs className="tabs-wrapper" id="menu">
      <TabList className="tabs">
        <Tab className="tab-item">Burgers</Tab>
        <Tab className="tab-item">Lunch of the day</Tab>
        <Tab className="tab-item">Crepes</Tab>
      </TabList>
      <TabPanel>
        <div className="burgers">
          <ul> 
          {burgers.map(burger => (
            <li key={burger.id}>
            <h4>{burger.title}</h4>
            <span>{burger.price}</span>
            <img src={burger.image} alt={burger.title} />
            <p>{burger.description}</p>
            <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(burger, "burger")}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
        <div className="lunch">
          <h4>Sweet lunch today!</h4>
          <span>7$</span>
          <p>You can choose one of our 3 sweet crepes + one of our 4 cold drinks!
            <br />
            Nutella crepe, Crepe with salted caramel and nuts or Oreo Bang crepe with whipped cream and raspberries.
            <br />
            For drink - one of our homemade lemonades - Melon, Orange or Lemon-Mint. Or a Frozen Coffee!
          </p>
          <div>
          <img src={sweetLunch} alt="Sweet crepe lunch" />
          <img src={sweetCrepes} alt="Sweet crepes lunch" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
      <div className="crepes">
          <ul>
          {crepes.map(crepe => (
            <li key={crepe.id}>
              <h4>{crepe.title}</h4>
              <span>{crepe.price}</span>
              <img src={crepe.image} alt={crepe.title} />
              <p>{crepe.description}</p>
              <button type="submit" onClick={() => addToCart(crepe, "crepe")}>Add to cart</button>
            </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
    <FontAwesomeIcon className="cart" icon={["fas", "shopping-cart"]} onClick={() => setCart(cart)}/>
  </>
  )
}
```

I want to make `Cart` component appear above `Menu` component, display on the right side and take a half of screen(like on Upwork when you click on jod in feed) when I click on `Cart` icon.

So I tried to import `Cart` component (which also holds a `Form`) into `Menu` component

```
const Cart = ({ cart }) => {
  const { image, title, price } = cart;

  return (
    <>
      <li>
        <img src={image} alt={title} />
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <span>{price}</span>
      </li>
      <Form />
    </>
  )
}
```

and got

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'image' of 'cart' as it is undefined.
at Cart (Cart.jsx:6)
```

My `App.jsx` looks like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import './App.css';
import './Responsive.css';

const Header = React.lazy(() => import("./components/Header"));
const Footer = React.lazy(() => import("./components/Footer"));

const Home = React.lazy(() => import("./components/Home"));
const Menu = React.lazy(() => import("./components/Menu"));

function App() {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <React.Suspense fallback={<p className="loader">Loading...</p>}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" render={props => <Home {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/menu" render={props => <Menu cart={cart} {...props} />} />
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Redirect to="/home" />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </React.Suspense>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try adding console.log (cart) what is the result?

Comment: console.log shows array items added to cart, when I click on cart item.

Comment: an array? not object? if an array, so you cannot destructure it like that

Comment: `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: "3", image: "/crepes-burgers/static/media/mushroom-burger.7a7ff9a6.jpg", title: "Mushroom", description: "100% beef, mushrooms in sour cream, red onion, arugula, cheddar, iceberg lettuce", price: "4$"}
1: {id: "2", image: "/crepes-burgers/static/media/italian-taste.d2d1b05f.jpg", title: "Italian taste", description: "100% Beef, mascarpone, black olives, dried tomatoes, red onion, arugula, iceberg lettuce", price: "4$"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: have you load your Chart component like this ? `charts.map((chart,index)=>{
 <Chart key={index} chart={chart}/>
});`

Comment: tried like this 
`{cart.map((cart, index) => { <Cart key={index} cart={cart}/> })};` 
But I don't have carts just cart

Comment: yeah it depends on your variable I just give an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230637/discussion-between-ati-and-juliar-nasution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some restructuring I managed to find an answer for displaying cart items

```
{cart.map((el) => (
        <Cart 
          key={el.id} 
          product={el} 
          removeFromCart={removeFromCart}
        />
      ))}
```

And Cart component itself

```
export default function Cart ({ product, removeFromCart })  {
  const { image, title, price } =  product;
```

Answer (score 0):

props which you try to pass is an empty table

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

<Menu cart={cart} />
```

Comment: I don't get it, it's confusing me